# Count letters in a text and produce an object with results

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to count letters in a text and get an object to display the letter count for each word.

So, for input `"Argument here"` expected output would be:

```
{ Argument: { A: 1, r: 2, g: 1, u: 1, m: 1, e: 3, n: 1, t: 1, ' ': 1, h: 1 },
  here: { e: 2, h: 1, r: 1} }
```

My attempt:

```
function LetterCountI(str) { 
 var arr = str.split(" "); var cCount = {}; var anotherO = {}; var final = {};
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(cCount[arr[i]]){
        cCount[arr[i]]++;
    } else {
        cCount[arr[i]] = 1;
    }
}        

var letterCount = str.split("");
 for(var j = 0; j < letterCount.length; j++){

    if(anotherO[letterCount[j]]){
        anotherO[letterCount[j]]++;
    } else {
        anotherO[letterCount[j]] = 1;
    }
    }

for(var property in cCount){
  final[property] = anotherO;
}

return final;

}

LetterCountI("Argument here");
```

What I currently get is

```
{ Argument: { A: 1, r: 2, g: 1, u: 1, m: 1, e: 3, n: 1, t: 1, ' ': 1, h: 1 },
  here: { A: 1, r: 2, g: 1, u: 1, m: 1, e: 3, n: 1, t: 1, ' ': 1, h: 1 } }
```

Comment: `let count=s=>[].reduce.call(s,(a,c)=>(a[c]=(a[c]||0)+1,a),{})`, then split and count for each word.

Comment: not able to understand the question. Can you please explain what is the object and what output you are expecting?

Comment: as I understand: you have a string and you need to produce an object which contains words of your texts as properties and each property contains an object which contains letters as properties and amount of these letters in the word as a value

Comment: Your expected output makes no sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for responding guys. Yea, my question is what smnbbrv described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **your approach can fail**. If your text just for fun contains `__proto__` or another `Object` property this property will give you an error / unexpected result. Anyway, if you are still sure you want to use this method instead of e.g. hash maps, you can go on with solutions below.

If you care about faster way of doing this you can use the following code:

```
function count(string) {
  var tmpname = '', tmpvalue = {}, result = {}, i = string.length;

  while (i--) {
    var letter = string[i];

    if (letter === ' ') {
      result[tmpname] = tmpvalue;
      tmpname = '';
      tmpvalue = {};
    }
    else {
      tmpname = letter + tmpname;
      tmpvalue[letter] = (tmpvalue[letter] || 0) + 1;
    }
  }

  if (tmpname) {
    result[tmpname] = tmpvalue;
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(count("Argument here"));
```

This does not call `split` function, so it is theoretically faster than Max Mastalerz's solution which does at least 2 full loops by calling a `split` function two times. If you don't really care about performance or your texts are usually very short, you can use a bit shorter version of Max Mastalerz's solution to approach this:

```
function count(string) {
  return string.split(' ').reduce(function(a, b) {
    b.split('').reduce(function(c, d) {
      return (c[d] = (c[d] || 0) + 1 , c);
    }, a[b] = {});

    return a;
  }, {});
}

console.log(count("Argument here"));
```

It is doing just the same, first finding the words and then finding the letters of each word.

Comment: pftt... Perfectionist ;) Also I removed one loop from my code

Comment: @MaxMastalerz :) well, as long as he asks for things like this he's gonna implement some tool to automatically define the language, or count the words in big texts like a book or whatever, so all this could involve big texts scan, that's why I think performant version could be still useful

Comment: @MaxMastalerz you are producing one loop, yes, but there are still two additional loops in your code , because of `split` function. So you have outer loop for counting words and inner loops for counting letters for each word. If you sum up all the inner loops you'll have the same two full scan loops, or, in other words O(3N) complexity when my first solution has a complexity of O(2N): one _my_ loop and one loop from `split` function

Comment: @MaxMastalerz actually changed the first solution to have no `split` calls at all

Comment: @spaceDog you can always accept the answer as the best 'thank you' :)

Answer (score 4):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bh785wf/2/), The following will count letters in the words that make up a string:

```
function letterCounts(s) {
    var result = {};

    s.split(' ').forEach(function(e) {
        result[e] = {};
        e.split('').forEach(function(c) {
            if(!result[e][c]) { result[e][c]=0; }
            result[e][c]++;
        });
    });

    return result;
}

letterCounts('Argument Here');
```

The result is:

```
"{"Argument":{"A":1,"r":1,"g":1,"u":1,"m":1,"e":1,"n":1,"t":1},"Here":{"H":1,"e":2,"r":1}}"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @spaceDog If you found this to be "the answer" that helped, please accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using forEach is an easier method, but here's something a bit more vanilla:

```
function countLetters(string) {
var obj = {};
var arr = string.split(' ');
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  obj[arr[i]] = {};
  for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
   if (!obj[arr[i]][arr[i][j]]) {
    obj[arr[i]][arr[i][j]] = 1;
   } else {
    obj[arr[i]][arr[i][j]]++;
  }
}
} return obj;
}



console.log(countLetters("Argument here"));
```